# Using fscanf in MATLAB to read an unknown number of columns

Tags: matlab, scanf

I want to use [`fscanf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html) for reading a text file containing 4 rows with an unknown number of columns. The newline is represented by two consecutive spaces.

It was suggested that I pass `:` as the [`sizeA`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html#inputarg_sizeA) parameter but it doesn't work.

How can I read in my data?

update: The file format is

```
String1 String2 String3
10 20 30
a b c
1 2 3
```

I have to fill 4 arrays, one for each row.

Comment: how about some code and sample file to illustrate your problem/expected output?

Comment: Do you need to use `fscanf`?

Comment: I need to use fscanf.
The file is for example
A B C D E\n
10 20 30 40\n
NAME1 NAME NAME3 NAME4\n

Comment: Please edit your sample data into the question, not posted as a comment. The newline characters in this example are not 2 consecutive spaces as you state in your question. Also, please explain *why* you need to use `fscanf`.

Comment: use  `importdata` instead.

Comment: You question implies that the scanned data is all on one line. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

See if this will work for your application.

```
fid1=fopen('test.txt');
i=1;
check=0;
while check~=1
    str=fscanf(fid1,'%s',1);
    if strcmp(str,'')~=1;
     string(i)={str};
    end
    i=i+1;
    check=strcmp(str,'');
end
fclose(fid1);
X=reshape(string,[],4);
ar1=X(:,1)
ar2=X(:,2)
ar3=X(:,3)
ar4=X(:,4)
```

Once you have 'ar1','ar2','ar3','ar4' you can parse them however you want.

Comment: i want to find a general solution. A professor said me to use : in sizeA

Comment: @Antonio I'm not sure why he would suggest that, it's not valid syntax.

Comment: @excza if i would read element by element using fscanf how could i do?

Comment: @Antonio use `sizeA = 1`, but this will not capture the shape of your data

Comment: @wiggens other than this code not actually working (`fileID ~= fid1`), both `fscanf` and `fgetl` increment the line counter so you're going to miss a lot of data.

Comment: @excaza You are right. I now edited the code to capture all of the data.

Comment: @Antonio The code above will only work if there are the same elements in  each of the rows. If it is like you stated in the question it will work fine. If it is like what you said in a comment "The file is for example A B C D E\n 10 20 30 40\n NAME1 NAME NAME3 NAME4\n", the code will crash. This is due to the fact that your first column has 5 elements while the rest have 4.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, i don't know if it is the only one but it works fine:

```
A=fscanf(fid,'%[^\n] *\n')
B=sscanf(A,'%c ')
Z=fscanf(fid,'%[^\n] *\n')
C=sscanf(Z,'%d')
....
```

Comment: This could be fine, but it assumes the format of the input data. If it ever changes, this will need to be rewritten. Perhaps that is OK?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
rawText = getl(fid);
lines = regexp(thisLine,'  ','split);
tokens = {};
for ix = 1:numel(lines)
    tokens{end+1} = regexp(lines{ix},' ','split'};
end
```

This will give you a [cell array](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) of strings having the row and column shape or your original data. 
To read an arbitrary line of text then break it up according the the formating information you have available. My example uses a single space character.

This uses regular expressions to define the separator. Regular expressions powerful but too complex to describe here. See the MATLAB help for [regexp](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html?refresh=true) and [regular expressions](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html).